# GetAsync API in c# is not working when parameter are added dynamically

Tags: c#, get, request, dotnet-httpclient

```
Uri URL = new Uri($"https://authenticom.azure-api.net/dv-delivery/v1/delivery/?requestId={requestId}&pageSize={pageSize}")
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URL).Result;
```

above is failing with bad request, but when i add generated string as hardcoded its working fine

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://authenticom.azure-api.net/dv-delivery/v1/delivery/?requestId=1994bb2d-afc3-4323-b7da-c2c695dd4307&pageSize=100").Result;
```

Comment: What is the final runtime value of `$"https://authenticom.azure-api.net/dv-delivery/v1/delivery/?requestId={requestId}&pageSize={pageSize}"`? SIde note: do not use `.Result` as it can deadlock, instead use `await client.GetAsync...` also `response` needs a `using`

Comment: Try debugging and check the values of `requestId` and `pageSize` at runtime, might be null or having wrong values. Let me know if they have same values as hard coded example or not

Comment: values are coming fine in debugging, and if i hit formed URL in postman it also working